# Choose a dc-dc step up boost regulator

Tags: switching-regulator

I'm designing a circuit that runs on a single cell LiPo battery and I'm trying to choose a proper dc to dc step-up regulator. My circuit needs about 2A maximum. I searched a lot and found so many ICs.A noticeable difference between them is efficiency but not saying clearly in the datasheet for my 3.7 input voltage. For example, I don't know what is exactly different between TI's `lm2623` and `tps6185`. In specs, I almost see the same specs but the packaging is completely different. On the other hand, there are other manufacturers that have ICs with higher efficiency and lower price like `MT3608` which says it has almost 97% efficiency. How can I choose which one is good for me? I mean better efficiency and stability on high loads. Actually, I'm getting confused by which parameters I should consider.

Comment: 2A from a single cell sounds a bit nasty. It won't last long and there will be lots of heat. Is it 2A peak or continuous current? What kind of application is it?

Comment: @Lundin No, I mean the peak current. I'm using a GSM Modem.

Comment: This has been flagged as a product recommendation question. It is not. OP asks which parameters to look for, which is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several parameters, the regulator must meet voltage and current range requirements most controllers are stable if constructed correctly. Only you can decide the trade off between cost and efficiency.

The more modern higher frequency regulators are more expensive but will need less expensive components around them consider the cost of the whole regulator not just the controller.